# binascii.Error: Odd-length string for Python Implementation of Bitcoin

Tags: python

https://gist.github.com/vivosmith/f0e692d9aedbc39ec8d3eb4651bc107c

I was trying to implement [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tX-XokHf_nI) in Python 3

But the issue is that, it was implemented in Python 2

So I tried to implement this with binascii instead of encode/decode. However I keep getting a binascii.Error: Odd-length string at line 22.

How to I correct this? Or if this is completely broken, then is there any other libraries that work better for python 3?

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
import os
import ecdsa
import binascii
import hashlib

private_key = os.urandom(32)
PK_EN = binascii.hexlify(private_key)
print("Your Key" + "  " + str(PK_EN))
PK_CON = binascii.unhexlify(PK_EN)
sk = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(PK_CON, curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)
vk = sk.verifying_key
msg = binascii.hexlify(b'Hello')
sign_msg = sk.sign(msg)
assert vk.verify(sign_msg, msg)

public_key = b'04' + binascii.hexlify(vk.to_string())
print(public_key)

ripemd160 = hashlib.new('ripemd160')

ripemd160.update(hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(public_key)).digest())
```

I've changed the way you concatenated the public key with the prefix, and the call to the `ripmd160.update`, since it was expecting a string, not a Hash object.